# Selenium IDE - How to check text is not present within a specific element

Tags: selenium-ide

Is there any way to check there is no occurrence of a particular string of text within a specific element?

The challenge I have is the same string of text is repeated multiple times throughout the page. I can pinpoint the single element I am checking within but am stuck at making sure the text is not displayed within it.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont know anything about selenium,but why dont you can use regular expression? And it would be better if you post your code toooo :)

Answer (score 1):

In Selenium IDE you can use the command `assertText` to verify weather the element has particular text or not.

`Command` - assertText
`Target` - locator id
`Value` - Text to check.

The above command would pass when the element have the exact text you mentioned and it fails if it is not present.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this 
verifyEval | this.page().findElement("//input[@id='ElementID']").value != 'string' | false

Where ElementID is the id of the HTML element (in this case an INPUT element, and "string" is the search string you are trying to verify does not exist in the element.

Hope this helps